# Get all country names used in Bing Maps SOAP Services

Tags: c#, web-services, bing-maps

I am using the Bing Maps SOAP Service, [GeocodeService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd221354.aspx) in my web application, to reverse geocode a point on map (i.e. get country name from longitude and latitude). I need to get all the exact country names that the web service can return. I tried to get all the country names from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd435699) but for example 'Macedonia, Former Yugoslav Republic of' is returned of 'FYRO Macedonia' in the web service. Is there a way to get all exact country names possible that the web service can return since I need to store them in a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

brute force? (you may miss vatican city, but I'd expect you'd get the others, it will also spend a lot of time trying to geocoding oceans)

```
        GeoServiceReference.GeocodeServiceClient client = new GeoServiceReference.GeocodeServiceClient();

        var countries = new List<string>();

        for (double lat = 0; lat < 360; lat+=0.1)
            for(double lon = 0; lon < 360; lon+=0.1)
        {
            var result = client.ReverseGeocode(new GeoServiceReference.ReverseGeocodeRequest
            {
                Location = new GeoServiceReference.Location
                {
                    Latitude = lat,
                    Longitude = lon
                }
            });

            if (!countries.Contains(result.Results.First().Address.CountryRegion))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result.Results.First().Address.CountryRegion);
                countries.Add(result.Results.First().Address.CountryRegion);
            }
        }
```

Comment: A couple of points: first, latitude varies from -90 to +90, longitude varies from -180 to +180... neither one goes from 0 to 360 :) Secondly, if my maths is correct, this approach brute-force geocodes over 12 *million* points and, as you say yourself, most of them are in the ocean. Rather than incremental looping, why not set up a list containing the latitude/longitude of all world capital cities and then look up the country returned for each of those? A short amount of time to build the list in the first place, but then you'll need to make only 200 geocodes or so - one for each country.

Comment: @AlastairAitchison yes, I agree with you on each of your points, there is a list of capital cities here: http://lab.lmnixon.org/4th/worldcapitals.html although I don't know how complete it is